# Input data received all in lowercase on spark streaming in databricks using DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

My spark streaming application consumes data from an `aws kenisis` and is deployed in `databricks`. I am using the `org.apache.spark.sql.Row.mkString` method to consume the data and the whole data is received in lowercase. The actual input had camel case field name and values but is received in lowercase on consuming.

I have tried consuming from a simple java application and is receiving the data in the correct from from the kinesis queue. The issue is only in the spark streaming application using DataFrames and running in databricks.

```
// scala code

val query = dataFrame
      .selectExpr("lcase(CAST(data as STRING)) as krecord")
      .writeStream
      .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {

        def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
          true
        }

        def process(row: Row) = {
          logger.info("Record received in data frame is -> " + row.mkString)
          processDFStreamData(row.mkString, outputHandler, kBase, ruleEvaluator)
        }

        def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
        }
      })
      .start()
```

Expectation is the spark streaming input json should be in the same case 
letter (camel case)as the data in the kinesis , it should not be converted to lower case once received using data frame.

Any thought's on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the lcase used in the select expression was the culprit, updated the code as below and it worked.

val query = dataFrame
      .selectExpr("CAST(data as STRING) as krecord")
      .writeStream
      .foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
.........